# Cannot import matplotlib in script called from PHP

Tags: php, python, matplotlib, import

I have a python script, `analysis.py`, which imports the library matplotlib. This is the beginning of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import convert
from itertools import groupby
import sys

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
```

I am calling this file from a php script, in this way:

```
$input = 'python /var/www/Project/analysis.py';
$command = escapeshellcmd($input);
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo '<pre>'.$output.'</pre>';
```

But it fails at importing matplotlib. Matplotlib is imported just fine in every other situation, but not here. The output of `sys.path` is the same whether the script runs or fails. I tried a workaround by calling a `test.py` from the php and having that script in turn call `analysis.py` in this manner:

```
import os
command = "python /var/www/Project/analysis.py"
os.system(command)
```

But the result is the same. Why doesn't php allow matplotlib to import? And, more importantly, how do I fix or avoid the issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try changing to the working directory of your python script before executing. $input = 'cd  /var/www/Project/; python /var/www/Project/analysis.py'; or chdir(' /var/www/Project/');

Comment: I don't think that's right... Not only does that not fix my problem, but I tried it on other scripts that do work (because they don't have matplotlib) and your command fails there too.